# Python Dataframe Column value update for multi condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, updates

Hello i want to simplfy the code below. It works but i want to create a dictionary for C9, 4A, C8 and want to do the same code with a single statement.

```
df.loc[df["Column"] =="C9","New_Column"]="LCV"
df.loc[df["Column"] =="4A"," New_Column"]="LCV"
df.loc[df["Column"] =="C8","New Column"]="LCV"
```

there is 10 lines of statament like that.
If the column value is C9 or 4A or C8 i want to update the new column value to LCV.

i will be grateful if you can help me.

Best Regards..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[`pd.Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html)**:

```
>>> df.loc[df["Column"].isin(["4A", "C8", "C9"]),"New_Column"]="LCV"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
values = ["C9", "4A", "C8"]
df.loc[df["Column"].isin(values), "New_Column"]="LCV"
```

Answer (score 0):

I use **apply** function, and I passed to it a lambda function that will check each row if the column value is in the items it will put the "LVC" to the value of New_Column otherwise it will put None.

```
items = ["C9", "4A", "C8"]
df["New_Column"] = df.apply(lambda row: "LVC" if row.Column in items else None, axis = 1)
```